Autocompletionservice.getpredictions: failed to load resource: net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED
I had develop the web application for google map api address search
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=apikey&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
This is googlemap api url
when search the address I had called initAutocomplete callback

window.initAutocomplete = function (searchText, compoent, name) {
    try {
        const strictBoundsInputElement = document.getElementById(
            "use-strict-bounds"
        );
        const options = {
            fields: ["formatted_address", "address_components", "geometry", "name"],
            strictBounds: false,
            types: ["premise"],
        };
 
        if (name == "Ordering")
            var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($("#autocomplete")[0], { options, strictBoundsInputElement });

        autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions({ 'country': ['uk'] });
        autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions("bounds");
 
        const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        const infowindowContent = document.getElementById(
            "infowindow-content"
        );
        infowindow.setContent(infowindowContent);
 
        const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
 
            anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29),
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function (e) {
            infowindow.close();
            marker.setVisible(false);
 
            place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            if (!place.geometry || !place.geometry.location) {
                window.alert("No details available for input: '" + place.name + "'");
                return;
            }
 
            marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
            marker.setVisible(true);
 
            var street_addr = autocomplete.getPlace().formatted_address;
            var latitude = autocomplete.getPlace().geometry.location.lat();
            var langitude = autocomplete.getPlace().geometry.location.lng();
            var placeResult = autocomplete.getPlace();
            var addressComponents = placeResult.address_components;
            var street = "";
            var number = "";
            var premise = "";
            var postalcode = "";
            var administrative_area_level_1 = "";
            var administrative_area_level_2 = "";
            var locality = "";
            var postal_town = "";
            var country = "";
         
 
 
        });
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
        // Call the error callback function and pass the error message
        //errorCallback(error.message);
    }
 
};


#autocomplete is textbox when internet not have i.e offline at the time if we search the address ,
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/js/AutocompletionService.GetPredictions this api failed fetch that means
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED . This error find on browser console. I am unable to catch this exception on scriptside using catch block. I want to handle this exception if failed to feacth the api then i want to show user friendly message to enduser. How will handle properly and show the user fridenly message
